# Parsing a String to see if it contains another String, and then returning a monad if it does

Tags: haskell

I was writing a function (named `listenString`) in haskell to see if a string contains one of the strings in a list of strings, and to then return a value (of the type `m ()`) that corresponded with the string it found. The type of that function is `(Eq a, Monad m) => [a] -> [([a], m ())] -> m ()`.

The reason why I used a list to store the strings and their corresponding values (`[([a], m ())]`) instead of a Map was because I wanted to make sure that the function evaluated strings in the order that they were in the list, e.g. `listenString "hello there" [("lo",print True),("hello",print False)]` would printed `True`. If I used a map, the order might have been lost, and the function might have printed `False`.

Here's the code. I'm specifically wondering if there are any bugs, and if I'm using `ListT` correctly (of if I should be using something other than `ListT`), but any other feedback would be helpful and appreciated.

```
import Data.Either
import Control.Monad.Trans.List

searchListMapMaybe f (Search a b c) = Search a (mapMaybe f b) c

data Search a b = Search a [a] b

type Searching a b = ListT (Either b) (Search a b)

listenString [] _ = return ()
listenString a l = 
                    let list = filter (\(x,_) -> if (x == []) then False else True) l
                        noEmptyList [] = error "listenForString: You need to have at least one item in the list"
                        noEmptyList x = x
                     in listenStringSub a $ ListT $ Data.Either.Right $ fmap (\(x,y) -> Search x [] y) $ noEmptyList list
    where
    listenStringSub :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Searching [a] (m b) -> m b
    listenStringSub _ (ListT (Data.Either.Left a)) = a
    listenStringSub (c:cs) x = listenStringSub cs $ (listenStringMap c x) >>= searchFinal
        where
        listenStringMap char x = fmap ((searchReduce char) . (searchPop char)) x
    searchPop :: (Eq a) => a -> Search [a] b -> Search [a] b
    searchPop char (Search a@(x:_) l b) 
      | char == x = Search a (a:l) b
      | otherwise = Search a l b
    searchReduce :: (Eq a) => a -> Search [a] b -> Search [a] b
    searchReduce char search = searchListMapMaybe (function char) search
        where
        function _ [] = Just []
        function c l@(x:xs)
          | c == x = Just xs
          | otherwise = Nothing
    searchFinal :: (Eq a) => Search [a] b -> Searching [a] b
    searchFinal s@(Search a b c) 
      | [] `elem` b = ListT (Data.Either.Left c)
      | otherwise = return s
```

**Edit:** `listenString` should decide what values to return in the following order:

1. Which list comes first: `listenString "hello there" [("lo",print True),("he",print False)]` would output `False`.
2. If two or more strings end in the exact same place, e.g.  `listenString "hello there" [("lo",print True),("hello",print False)]`, I want the tuple closest to the beginning of the list to be displayed (the above expression would output `True`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need the element type to be a monad? The only point you require it is when you do `return ()` in order to signal failure. I'd propose implementing a more general function

```
lookupSublist :: Eq a => [a] -> [([a], b)] -> Maybe b
```

Which could be implemented as:

```
lookupSublist xs = fmap snd . listToMaybe . filter (flip isInfixOf xs . fst)
```

So we first filter out all alternatives where the first element doesn't have `xs` as infix. Then we return the second element of the first remaining element, if any.

Some random notes on your code:

1. Using `noEmptyList` as a guard mid-expression isn't a good idea. Using `error` is pretty "evil" in the first place, you don't want to bury it like that. Putting the `list` in the `where` would allow you to say `listenString a l | null list = error...`
2. `(\(x,_) -> if (x == []) then False else True)` is simply `not . null . fst`. I'm not quite sure why you filter for that, to be honest. Wouldn't having `[]` in the list be a pretty elegant way to implement a default fallback value?
3. I am actually quit struggling to understand the rest of your code. I am pretty sure that your usage of `ListT` actually hurts more than it helps - generally when you start pattern-matching on the contents of a monad you are doing something wrong. Could you explain what you tried to do?

---

**Edit:** If the position of the match end should take priority, I would propose going over the prefixes of the string and suffix-test the options:

```
lookupFirstSublist str opts = listToMaybe $ mapMaybe f $ inits opts
  where f s = fmap snd $ listToMaybe $ filter (flip isSuffixOf s . fst) opts
```

Comment: I like this save one thing, I would instead of Maybe b have Maybe [a] -> b and use ap on it this way you could compose chains

Comment: `lookupSublist xs = fmap (\x -> Just \y -> (snd x) y) . filter (isInFixOf xs . fst)` for `lookupSublist :: Eq [a] => [a] -> [([a], [a] -> b)] -> [Maybe [a] -> b]`

Comment: `lookupSublist` doesn't work at all: I'm assuming that you meant `listenList a xs =  fmap snd $ listToMaybe (filter (\x -> isInfixOf (fst x) a) xs)`. Even then, your implementation of `lookupSublist` has some problems: `listenList "hello there" [("lo",True),("he",False)]` returns `True` (It should return `False`, because `"he"` comes first in the `"hello there"`).

Comment: Thanks for your help though: I'll post an explanation of the code and I'll respond to your other points when I have time to edit it.

Comment: It works fine here... Your version just removes the currying. Are you sure you copied it right? I'll add my solution for the new problem in a bit.

Comment: Nevermind, there was actually a `flip` missing. Sorry about that :)